# How to invoke methods of a generic type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

In this example the `asString()` invocations do not compile.  (Aside: Invoking `toString()` does compile but I need to customize.)  How do I invoke asString, or any method, of a generic type, given that the method has in fact been provided for every possible `T`?

```
class Range<T>
{
    private T min;
    private T max;

    Range(T min, T max)
    {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }  

    String makeString()
    {
        return "The range is from " + min.asString() + " to " + max.asString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide an interface that has `asString` method defined, for example:

```
interface AsStringable {
    String asString();
}
```

Then define your class like this:

```
class Range<T extends AsStringable>
{
    private T min;
    private T max;

    Range(T min, T max)
    {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }  

    String makeString()
    {
        return "The range is from " + min.asString() + " to " + max.asString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can customize `toString()` by overriding it in your class - no need for a new method.

And about your code: the compiler should know what you know - i.e. that `T` will always have a given method. Currently you tell it only that there is `T` which is any `Object`. If it is limited to subtypes of `Foo` which defines `asString()`, then use `<T extends Foo>`

```
public interface Foo {
    String asString();
}

public class Range<T extends Foo> { .. }
```